# Proof that $d_{ij}=\sqrt{2(1-\rho_{ij})}$

Tags: real-analysis

How can we proof that $d_{ij}=\sqrt{2(1-\rho_{ij})}$, where $d_{ij}$ is distant between vector $i$ and vector $j$, while $\rho_{ij}$ is correlation coefficient between vector $i$ and vector $j$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the vector $i$ and $Y$ be the vector $j$ (since we do not usually use $i$ and $j$ for vector names).

$$d(X,Y)=\sqrt{\|X-Y\|^2}=\sqrt{\|X\|^2+\|Y\|^2-2\langle X,Y \rangle}.$$

Now I guess that your vectors have unit norm and that the correlation coefficient is the dot product of $X$ and $Y$. This gives your result.

Comment: Thank you. Because $||X||=1$, $||Y||=1$, and $2<X,Y>$=$\rho_{XY}$, then $d(XY)=\sqrt(2(1-\rho_{XY})$.

Comment: Actually $\rho_{XY}=\langle X,Y \rangle$ without the factor $2$ @Budi